# I am trying to run an app android studio giraffe version, keep getting error in layout bolded line is my error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-xml

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="1246dp"
        android:layout_height="783dp"
        android:gravity="bottom|center|end|top|start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_sail"
        android:layout_width="486dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_sail"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_sail" />

  **  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_title"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="620dp"
        android:layout_height="427dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
        android:text="@string/txt_description"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDate"
        android:layout_width="602dp"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_date"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.536"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am very new with android studio, as in, my second week! Please explain this to me and guide me to a solution? I cannot run my tablet intended application! Again, I am novice and want to learn the solution. Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions that you may have!The app should look like this if it helps? I am willing to provide any other details that are needed to clarify the situation!

Comment: Please clarify your question: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: The dialog from your screenshot is the general description of the element, not the error message. Please post the error message from the build tab or the console where all the compile logs are shown. Preferably copy the console text, edit your question and insert it as text (and format it as code), not as screenshot.

Comment: 3 errors as follows:
`@+id/textView3` is not a sibling in the same `ConstraintLayout`
for line 38,39, and 40 also the last error states unexpected end of file at line 92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- i have notice that tag `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` not closed you should make end tag like `</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
- my advice to you that you should to learn just basic of android xml you will move through these problems